# Open url multiple times at the same times, like fiddler on c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Ineed to pragmatically open one link multiple times at the same time, but the link must set cookies on the web, i finish this part but i cant repeat open url like fiddler, can you help me?

```
string url = "https://www.google.com.mx";
Uri target = new Uri(url);
CookieContainer gaCookies = new CookieContainer();
gaCookies.Add(new Cookie("dosid", textBox1.Text) { Domain = target.Host });
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
myReq.CookieContainer = gaCookies;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it using await/async. You really do not want to do too many at the same time. It would be best to implement a way to using maybe semaphores or something to only allow so many at a time to process. But this meets your requirements:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<string> urls = new List<string>
    {
        "https://www.google.com.mx",
        "https://www.google.com.mx",
        "https://www.google.com.mx",
        "https://www.google.com.mx",
    };


    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    var results = new List<string>();

    foreach (string url in urls)
    {
        var webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        CookieContainer gaCookies = new CookieContainer();
        gaCookies.Add(new Cookie("dosid", textBox1.Text) { Domain = /*target.Host*/ "google.com" });
        webReq.CookieContainer = gaCookies;

        tasks.Add(GetURLContentsAsync(webReq));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks); //wait for all the urls to finish loading

    foreach (Task<string> task in tasks) //get the results of all the web requests
    {
        results.Add(await task);
    }

}

private async Task<string> GetURLContentsAsync(HttpWebRequest webReq)
{
    var content = new MemoryStream();

    using (WebResponse response = await webReq.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            await responseStream.CopyToAsync(content);
        }
    }
    var buffer = content.ToArray();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Comment: the name target do not exist in the actual context
the name GetURLContentsAsync do not exitst in the actual  context 
help!

Comment: target was from your code, i figured you would handle it like you are handling in your existing code. I changed it to "google.com" but it has to match the url youre building the cookie for. in this case it is "google.com". As far as GetURLContentsAsync... please see the example code. that function is there. You maybe didn't include it when you copied and pasted...... I slightly changed the code above to fix "Target" issue

Comment: how watch do the code in real time? why i dont see nothing about the functions